# How to remove white spaces in asp.net List View?

Tags: asp.net

[Image showing the inconsitency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn5ks.png)

I am binding ListView from database,and I've fixed the image height but still the height of listview item is not consistence.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot

Comment: "enter image description here" is  a image link at top of question.

Comment: Add an empty line between the weight and the price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because your listview items are floating left besides each other, and when there's one that is taller than the others it forces the extrange alignment that you're seeing. In your example the "MOONG CHINLKA" product has two lines for price and weight, while the others only have one. That makes the whole item taller and breaks your layout.

One possible solution is forcing the height of your list items to be enough for the tallest possible, so all of them would be equal. That would solve your problem.